# Fan control on Asus K401UQ in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, hardware, asus, fan, fancontrol

I'm almost happy with my Asus K401UQ-FA079T and Ubuntu 17.10. I can't get the fan to be quiet when the computer is not under heavy CPU load.

Fan control is not provided by the kernel. Fans are not detected by the Asus WMI generic driver. I think main fan is controlled by the BIOS because its speed increases when i run a game or something CPU consuming. No problem with that. My problem is that the minimum fan speed (when i do nothing, with CPU temp under 40°C) is quite high and it is noisy. It almost never stops except in a cold room if i avoid touching it during 10 minutes !

I tried to compile and use [asus-fan module](https://github.com/daringer/asus-fan) but as the K401UQ is not supported, i wasn't able to load this module.

The only sensor detected by lm-sensors's `sensors-detect` is `coretemp` so `pwmconfig` can't help me for the moment.

Anyone is having the same problem and has found something useful ?

Here is the result of `dmesg | grep asus` :

```
[   11.243181] asus_wmi: ASUS WMI generic driver loaded
[   11.293911] asus_wmi: Initialization: 0x1
[   11.293935] asus_wmi: BIOS WMI version: 9.0
[   11.293950] asus_wmi: SFUN value: 0x21
[   11.294422] input: Asus WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input8
[   11.294488] asus_wmi: Number of fans: 0
[   12.453703] asus 0018:0B05:0101.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [FTE1001:00 0B05:0101] on i2c-FTE1001:00
[17385.205329] asus_wmi: Unknown key cf pressed
```

Here is the result of `dmidecode -t 2` :

```
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
        Product Name: K401UQK
        Version: 1.0       
        Serial Number: QCXXXXXXXXXXXX
        Asset Tag: ATN000000000000000
        Features:
                Board is a hosting board
                Board is replaceable
        Location In Chassis: MIDDLE              
        Chassis Handle: 0x0003
        Type: Motherboard
        Contained Object Handles: 0
```

Comment: Check your BIOS for fan settings. Some systems have a "Fan Always On" toggle.

Comment: @ravery : There is no such setting in my BIOS :-(